# C#: how to programmatically get share link for a Dropbox folder and file

Tags: c#, .net, dropbox, dropbox-api

How to programmatically get share link for a Dropbox folder and file?

There are numerous of posts but I didn't find a simple solution for this. Can someone point me to the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you show us your code and tell us what's going wrong, someone might be able to help. Shortcut:

```
POST https://api.dropbox.com/1/shares/auto/<path> HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer <access token>

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "url": "https://...",
    "expires": "<a REALLY long time from now>"
}
```

See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares.